# Grab all groups a user is apart of

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to out to the screen all groups a certain user belongs too:

```
Connect-MsolService
Connect-AzureAD
Import-Module AzureAD
$UserName = "user.email@company.com"
$groups = Get-AzureADGroup | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Members -contains $UserName}
foreach ($group in $groups) {
        $props = @{'Name'           = $group.Name;
                   'DisplayName'    = $group.DisplayName;
                   'Identity'       = $group.SamAccountName;
                   'PrimaryEmail'   = $group.WindowsEmailAddress}

        $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props
        Write-Output $obj
    }
```

But nothing happens with this, am i filtering wrong? I have been using the MsolService and AzureAD modules because i can not seem to get ActiveDirectory modules to work, but thats a separate question. This code doesnt throw any errors, but i do not know why nothing outputs to the screen.

Comment: Are the members of the group using their email addresses as the name? You're filtering on a variable called `$UserName`, but your example shows an email address being added.

Comment: With AD, the property containing members is called `Member` and the names are stored as distinguished names

Comment: Is this for Azure AD, or for on prem AD?

Comment: Jason, I want to use the email address of users since it is unique, will $_.Members not filter on the email address?

Micky- is there a filter in AD for email addresses?

TheMadTech - I am not sure, i am new to powershell, and i could not get the activedirectory modules to load or find an AD server, and i found that the msol and the AzureAD modules will load and pull the correct resources so i went with those!

Hope this helps explain.